# Rotating a BufferedImage gives it a black border

Tags: java, bufferedimage, image-rotation, affinetransform

I try to rotate a BufferedImage and it works, but the rotated image has a black border around some sides and I don't know why... 
I also feel like it gets smaller after rotating.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.AffineTransformOp;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class example {

   static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedImage imgResc = ImageIO.read(new File("landscape.jpg"));        

        AffineTransform tx = new AffineTransform();
        tx.rotate(Math.PI / 2, imgResc.getWidth() / 2, imgResc.getHeight() / 2);//(radian,arbit_X,arbit_Y)
        AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(tx, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_BILINEAR);
        BufferedImage rotatedImage = new BufferedImage(imgResc.getHeight(),imgResc.getWidth(),imgResc.getType());
        op.filter(imgResc, rotatedImage);
        ImageIO.write(rotatedImage, "JPEG", new File("rotated_90_right.jpg"));
    } 
}
```

Above is the code snippet for rotating the image like I found it online.

Help would be great!

EDIT:

This is how it should look like and what I get after rotating:
(1920 x 1200)

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that your width or height is odd? If so, your divisions by two will introduce rounding error, shrinking the image by a pixel. Is that the size of the border?

Comment: I edited the question and added an img of whats the result.

Comment: It also isn't rotated in what you posted...

Comment: @Andrew what dou you mean ?

Comment: The images I see have the same dimensions and orientation; the second one is just shrunk with a border but it is not rotated. Also looks like other people have had this problem too. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34143111/java-rotate-image-turns-part-of-background-black?rq=1

Comment: @Andre Ah I see, seems like a misunderstanding. I is basically what the Image should look like when rotated and the other is what i actually get.

Comment: @ViktorG Has the link that Andrew posted provides you with your answer? If so, let us know so we can close this question, okay?

Comment: @ControlAltDel Actually not... I tried the solution from the link but I get the same result.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès That Helped me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If you rotate by PI/2 then the new image has width the height of the source and height the width of the source, so:

```
BufferedImage rotatedImage = new BufferedImage(imgResc.getHeight(),
                                               imgResc.getWidth(),
                                               imgResc.getType());
```

would be better.

Comment: This is good advice, but it doesn't answer the question asked, as the OP described a black border around all sides, and the image possibly shrinking

Comment: You are right, thank you. The problem with the black border around still remains, though.